# My application won't run and got error when i put background on the layout

Tags: xml, background, styles, themes

This is android

When i tried with no background, it installed the apk and works fine. But when i input a background and getting the image in drawable. The application won run and got error. What is the problem. Ty

Comment: What you mean by "when i input a background"?

Comment: i call a picture in the drawable. and put it on the relativelayout, then when i it already installed, the application wont run